# Java , How can I pass a tree form output in a data collection type?

Tags: java, collections, tree

How can I pass the output of a method which has multiple level from one class to another in Java . Is there anything which can hold a "tree-like" data apart from tree itself?

for example : if I want to return String data type , the method will be like :

```
              private String method () {
                  return string; }
```

What kind of datatype can i use if I want to return an output like the following ?

```
enter code here
 :Thing
     :ValuePartition
     :Spiciness
         :Medium
     :DomainConcept
     :Food
         :IceCream
         :Pizza
             :NamedPizza
                 :Mushroom
                 :AmericanHot
                 :Caprina
                 :Margherita
             :MeatyPizza
             :NonVegetarianPizza
```

---

Comment: What do you mean by 'output of a class'?

Comment: You need to better define your problem and give more context, code example, ... if you want people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON: http://json.org/java/

Your function can return a `String` (Serialized JSON) or a `JSONObject` Type.

You JSONObject or String would look something like this.

```
{ 
     Thing : {
        ValuePartition : '',
        Spiciness : 'medium',
        DomainConcept : '',
        Food : ['IceCream','Pizza']
     }
}
```